# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to Integrate firebase with my flutter project but it is stopping while building gradle
saying
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
My flutter is fully upgraded, anyone tell me how to solve it.

I followed the steps of integrating firebase but it's build is failing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUBnJ.png)

Comment: Try upgrading firebase package version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in android `build.gradle` make sure to have this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
}
```

Comment: I have these dependecies but it's still not working

Comment: show me please.

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }